# Condition is (supposedly) met but expected action (plotchar) doesn't happen

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I'm trying to create a screener. It starts with plotting:

(a) Two red straight horizontal lines marking the highest high and the lowest low of the lookback period.
(b) Two blue straight horizontal lines marking 25% and 75% points from this range.

Please, check the screenshot.

My issue is: it should mark (plotchar) when ALL the four condition below are met, but it's not working atm.

(1) In the first half of the period, high has been in the upper range at least once.
(2) In the first half of the period, low has been in the lower range at least once.
(3) In the second half of the period, high has been in the upper range at least once.
(4) In the second half of the period, low crosses-under lower the range line.

Unless I'm missing something, all these four conditions are met in the screenshot, therefore it should be char-plotted in candle|4| (when LOW CROSSES-UNDER LOW RANGE LINE), but nothing was plotted.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Below, the relevant part of the code, but [all code is here](https://github.com/42piratas/misc/blob/master/3commas/screening_3commas_gridbots.pine) if you'd like to check and/or re-use.

```
lookBack = input(title="Lookback", type=input.integer, defval=24, minval=2)
range = input(title="Upper & Lower Range", type=input.integer, defval=4, minval=10)

// INDICATORS & VARIABLES

highestHigh = highest(high, lookBack)
lowestLow = lowest(low, lookBack)

xAxisStartsAt = bar_index[lookBack]
xAxisFinishesAt = bar_index

upperLimit = highestHigh
lowerLimit = lowestLow

upperRange = ((highestHigh - lowestLow)/range) + lowestLow
lowerRange = highestHigh - ((highestHigh - lowestLow)/range)

HighAboveUpperRange = high > upperRange
LowBelowLowerRange = low < lowerRange

occurrencesAboveTotal   = sum(HighAboveUpperRange ? 1 : 0, lookBack)
occurrencesAboveSecondHalf = sum(HighAboveUpperRange ? 1 : 0, lookBack/2)
occurrencesAboveFirstHalf  = occurrencesAboveTotal - occurrencesAboveSecondHalf

occurrencesBelowTotal   = sum(LowBelowLowerRange ? 1 : 0, lookBack)
occurrencesBelowSecondHalf = sum(LowBelowLowerRange ? 1 : 0, lookBack/2)
occurrencesBelowFirstHalf  = occurrencesBelowTotal - occurrencesBelowSecondHalf

// STRATEGY 

triggerA = occurrencesAboveFirstHalf >= 1 ? true : false
triggerB = occurrencesAboveSecondHalf >= 1 ? true : false
triggerC = occurrencesBelowFirstHalf >= 1 ? true : false
triggerD = crossunder(low, lowerRange)

condition = triggerA and triggerB and triggerC and triggerD

// PAINTBRUSH

plotchar(condition)
```

**Update**

In the second and third screenshots, stars (plotchar) were plotted, but not where they were expected (they are expected when LOW crosses under the lower blue line/lower range (condition 4).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, the formulas for determining the range are mixed up, you have so

```
upperRange = ((highestHigh - lowestLow)/range) + lowestLow
lowerRange = highestHigh - ((highestHigh - lowestLow)/range)
```

but it should be like this

```
lowerRange = ((highestHigh - lowestLow)/range) + lowestLow
upperRange = highestHigh - ((highestHigh - lowestLow)/range)
```

Add debug lines to your script, you will see a lot of useful information

```
plot(lowerRange,color=color.red)
plot(upperRange,color=color.green)
plot(low, color=color.black)
```

I'm not sure, but it seems to me that `crossunder(low, lowerRange)`
this is not the condition you would like to test.
Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! You solved it! And great tip on plotting to debug, I have been struggling to debug my issues with Pine (I'm pretty new to it). And I really want to check when a certain price enters the lower range in the second half of that cycle, therefore when LOW crossunder lowerRange in the second half. Does it make sense? Cheers! :-)

Comment: Checking this condition makes sense. I just wanted to draw your attention to the fact that 
`lowerRange != lowerRangeLine`

Comment: LOW crossunder `lowerRange`  and crossunder `lowerRangeLine` at different bars.